# Animation Compass Plugin not working in Middleman?

Tags: animation, plugins, middleman

Hi I have a problem adding animation plugin in middleman and yes I'm pretty sure I installed animation plugin for compass and I see it on my gem lists.

**if I add this on my config.rb**

```
require 'animation'
```

It shows an error and this is the output

```
/cygdrive/d/Main/dot_proj/config.rb:7:in `require': cannot load such file -- animation (LoadError)
        from /cygdrive/d/Main/dot_proj/config.rb:7:in `initialize'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.0.11/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/extensions.rb:137:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.0.11/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/extensions.rb:137:in `initialize'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.0.11/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/ruby_encoding.rb:22:in `initialize'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.0.11/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/data.rb:35:in `initialize'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.0.11/lib/middleman-core/application.rb:188:in `initialize'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.0.11/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/request.rb:56:in `new'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.0.11/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/request.rb:56:in `inst'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.0.11/lib/middleman-core/preview_server.rb:73:in `new_app'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.0.11/lib/middleman-core/preview_server.rb:154:in `mount_instance'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.0.11/lib/middleman-core/preview_server.rb:19:in `start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.0.11/lib/middleman-core/cli/server.rb:73:in `server'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor/base.rb:425:in `start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.0.11/lib/middleman-core/cli.rb:77:in `method_missing'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor/task.rb:29:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor/task.rb:126:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor/base.rb:425:in `start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.0.11/lib/middleman-core/cli.rb:22:in `start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-core-3.0.11/bin/middleman:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/bin/middleman:23:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/middleman:23:in `<main>'
```

**This is the link for the plugin**
https://github.com/ericam/compass-animation

I'm guessing that my middleman doesn't have the plugin installed on the middleman core itself? If yes then how do I add a compass plugin to my middleman?

Comment: My brother wrote middle man. Have you tried logging the issue in the middle man git bug tracker?

Comment: do `bundle show` and `bundle show animation`.